# Immutable.js and how to replace list with new list

Tags: immutable.js

So, I have a default Immutable List:

```
var someObject = Immutable.Map({
   myList: Immutable.List([4,5,6,7])
})
```

Now, I allow a person to overwrite this list, but I still need it to be contained within "someObject". Basically, if a user supplies an array, we replace what is in myList, with this "new List". I tried to accomplish like so, no luck.

basically, if this newList exists, use it - if not, either reset the myList to itself or ignore.

```
//example
var newList = [44444,99999]

                someObject.get('myList')
                    .clear()
                        .set('myList', newList || someObject.get('myList'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, because the objects supplied by immutable.js are immutable - that's their point.

Instead of trying to mutate someObject, one way to accomplish what you're trying to do would be to define a `defaultList = Immutable.List(4, 5, 6, 7)` and then build `someObject` *after* the user has input their list. Something along the lines of

```
if (userList) {
    someObject = Immutable.Map({myList: Immutable.List(userList)})
} else {
    someObject = Immutable.Map({myList: Immutable.List(defaultList)})
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, but this isn't scalable.. I should haven't test against myList, and if it doesn't exist, use defaultList. I don't understand how you can't "set" the immutable object with its helpers, with "new data". I have been doing with objects/Map -- updating and removing.. all I want to do with this ".List" is clear it out, and rehydrate it with user data.